# How to get Metadata of PDF in linux using Tika

Tags: java, ubuntu

I installed PDFs Printer in Ubuntu,so when i print any file it generates the .PDFs file now i wants to find out the metadata(i.e title,creation date,modified date,producer,author.etc....) of that PDFs using  TIKA or normal java.I tried with  jar in Ubuntu but it didn't give creation date and modified date.Is it possible for reading the total metadata of PDFs using  TIKA in Ubuntu.So anybody know how to get please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can have the [java program](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0419__PDF/Getmetadatafrompdfdocument.htm) for the same and you need to [download](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7/itext-2.1.7.jar) library file and add it to classpath

Adding java program from above mentioned link

Unfortunately do not have any idea about Tika, so hope it is okay for you to use in java way as you mentioned.

```java
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("2.pdf"); //change your filename
    Map info = reader.getInfo();
    for (Iterator i = info.keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
      String key = (String) i.next();
      String value = (String) info.get(key);
      System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
    }
    if (reader.getMetadata() == null) {
      System.out.println("No XML Metadata.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("XML Metadata: " + new String(reader.getMetadata()));
    }
  }

}
```

Output appear something like this:

```xml
ModDate: D:20120928204721+01'00'
Creator: Adobe Acrobat 10.0
CreationDate: D:20120916150806+01'00'
Producer: Adobe Acrobat 10.14 Paper Capture Plug-in with ClearScan
Title: 
XML Metadata: <?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.2-c001 63.139439, 2010/09/27-13:37:26        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
         <xmp:ModifyDate>2012-09-28T20:47:21+01:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
         <xmp:CreateDate>2012-09-16T15:08:06+01:00</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:MetadataDate>2012-09-28T20:47:21+01:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
         <xmp:CreatorTool>Adobe Acrobat 10.0</xmp:CreatorTool>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
         <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
         <xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:91129bea-7273-4b3d-924f-5f47a5b55fbf</xmpMM:DocumentID>
         <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:3a02e281-e35f-454a-bac1-adf1bb833636</xmpMM:InstanceID>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
         <pdf:Producer>Adobe Acrobat 10.14 Paper Capture Plug-in with ClearScan</pdf:Producer>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

Comment: In Windows that is working fine,but in linux it didn't give creation date,modified date and title of pdf file.So is there any way.

Comment: Does the pdf used have those properties set? I believe that it should not have dependency os. In fact the above code is run and output from linux only.

Comment: Yes the pdf having property set is Name,Size,Volume,Modified Date,Accessed date.But   Linux Ubuntu not working i tried, it given only creator producer values